# Django 2 different api calls for 2 different tables in postgres

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, postgresql

I have 2 API's, they are working with different tables in the same db. But when I call them at the same time, they are working not parallelly but one after other.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase database timeout option in your project settings.
Also you will have to use async approach to run APIs parallelly.